# Autofilter by criteria, should stop proceeding one of criteria if there is no data in particular column

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

My aim is to create procedure, which makes always filtering for one criterion (on the column I), but makes next one filtering for criterion (in the column T) provided that it exists.

To start with, I am a beginner, thus thank you for your patience and understanding.

The post is long, because I put screens how to work and how I wish it could work. It helps me out with explaining my problem.
I would like to implement my procedure for this simple range of cells:

[image]

Thus, we have this range of cells and we need to select a few values by filtering based on criteria:

```
Sub Filter1()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("C7:U7").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Lukasz" 
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("T:T"), "Check") > 0 Then
       sh.Range("C7:U7").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="Check" 
    
    End If
End Sub
```

It works properly if in the Column I we have value (for example “Lukasz”) and in the column T we have value “Check” as my procedure has been created.
[image]

Then, here is the main problem, As you can see for Lukasz in the column I, there are no "Check" values in the column T:
[image]
Unfortunately, after running my macro it shows empty cells, if we have in the column I data for name “Lukasz”, but there is no data for criterion “Lukasz” in the column T for “Data”, and I run the macro and the result  is:

[image]

**However, in that case, I would like to achieve it:**

[image]

Therefore, I do not have no idea how to either modify or create my procedure to stop filtering the column T based on criterion, if there is no “Check” values in this column.

Is it possible to either modify my macro or create new one to achieve my goal? If so, could you please modify my procedure and share it in order to achieve my goal? I will test it.

I would appreciate it if you could do it.

Comment: Do you want filtering by "Check" if "Check" exists in column T:T, or **if you can still see it after the first filtering**? Then, do you want filtering the column T:T (20), or column R:R (18),  as your code does?

Comment: Is your column to be filtered the one with the header "Check"? If yes, this should be the problem... And you should check the string existence starting from the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("T:T"), "Check")` counts all `Check` in the column `T` not only the visible ones.

```
Sub Filter1()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("C7:U7").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Lukasz" 

    Dim FilteredRange As Range  'get only visible cells in column T
    Set FilteredRange = sh.Range("T:T").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'search if Check can be found (we don't need to count them, one is enough!)
    If Not FilteredRange.Find(What:="Check", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=True) Is Nothing Then
        sh.Range("C7:U7").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="Check"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `CountIf` does not work with non-continous ranges like `FilteredRange` returns. But we can use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) as we are only interested in the existance of `Check` and not the amount of `Check`. The `Find` returns `Nothing` if `Check` was not found.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but unfortunately it does not work.. I have the same result as previous...

Comment: @lukasz93 Did you use it together with your first filter? See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I placed my post to show you my image with your code and the final result

Comment: @lukasz93 make sure your column header is **not** named `Check` as your search word. Then it will work.

Comment: Great it works, but if my column header is called "Check" it doesn't work. What do you think? is it mandatory to change this name of this header?